# SQL Server Management Studio panes setting, always show Diagram Pane, Criteria Pane and SQL Pane

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms, pane

I am regularly working with SQL Server Management Studio and always use the following panes to work with the data: Diagram, Criteria and SQL.

[SQL Panes that I always use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvCCw.jpg)

At the moment, I am just clicking on them each time that I want to use them (which is about 20 times a day) and I hope that there may be a setting in which these panes always show. I am fairly new and I haven't found this option yet.

Anyone knows of a View setting?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no such setting, but I believe the default keystroke shortcuts for these would be Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, and Ctrl+3 (Ctrl+4 will hide the results if you don't need/want that). 
Should be quick to just hold down ctrl and punch 1,2,3 on the numpad in sequence.  Hope that helps.